# overload std::find for custom classes

Tags: c++, find, overloading, stl-algorithm

Well is it possible/"good" to overload `std::find` for custom classes in objects? And then without overloading the equality operators. Say a container stores (smart) pointers to it's actual data, I really am not interested in the data layout or storage mode, I just want to find a certain data member....

Is it legal, "moral", to o this? If say I have a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<myClass> >` - or "even" a user defined container? Or should I always rely on `std::find_if` for cases like these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idiomatic solution would be to use [std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and give it a suitable predicate.

This keeps the code you have to write and maintain to a minimum, and decouples you from the specific container type.